# Spring - How to pass different types at once in JSON using PATCH

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jackson

i have a PATCH mapping method that currently accepts a `Map<String, Object>` as `@ResponseBody`, because i've seen `ReflectionUtils` as one of ways to implement the PatchMapping, but when I want to pass for example `String`, `Integer` and `Long`, then JSON doesn't distinguish which one are which one. I would like to  be able to pass EntityID which is Long, some Value which is Integer and some Strings at once.

This is my current Controller method

```java
@PatchMapping("/grades/{id}")
public GradeEto partialUpdate(@PathVariable("id") final Long id, @RequestBody Map<String, Object> updateInfo) {
    return gradeService.partialUpdate(id, updateInfo);
}
```

This is main part of the `ReflectionUtils` update

```
@Override
public GradeEto partialUpdate(Long id, Map<String, Object> updateInfo) {

    Grade grade = gradeRepository.findById(id).get();
    GradeEto gradeeto = GradeMapper.mapToETO(grade);
    updateInfo.forEach((key, value) -> {
        Field field = ReflectionUtils.findField(GradeEto.class, key);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        ReflectionUtils.setField(field, gradeeto, value);
    });
```

And i want to be able to pass for example

```json
{
    "value": 2,   <-- Integer
    "comment": "Test Idea",   <-- String
    "subjectEntityId": 2  <-- Long
}
```

But it gives me `IllegalArgumentException` currently

How should i do it? And if im doing it the wrong way then how should I do it?

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: When passing numbers in JSON as Map<String, Object> they are all always Integer, and I want them to be Integers and Longs somehow, or maybe im doing it the wrong way?

Comment: How should Jackson know that (without having type information) that it needs to be a long? It will then convert to an `Integer` if it fits in the number range.

Comment: So then what's the proper way to update multiple different types fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the functionality offered by Jackson to perform the partial update.

For that, instead of reading the data to patch as a `Map` you specify in your Controller the type of the request body as `ObjectNode`:

```
@PatchMapping("/grades/{id}")
public GradeEto partialUpdate(@PathVariable("id") final Long id,
                              @RequestBody ObjectNode updateInfo) {
    
    return gradeService.partialUpdate(id, updateInfo);
}
```

Then inside the Service to operate with `ObjectNode`s you need to turn `GradeEto` instance into a node tree using [`ObjectMapper.valueToTree()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#valueToTree-java.lang.Object-) (*assuming that Service class is a managed Bean you can inject `ObjectMapper` into it instead of instantiating it locally*).

Method [`ObjectNode.fields()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html#fields--) can be used to iterate over the fields and corresponding values of `updateInfo`. Methods [`isNull()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#isNull()) and [`isEmpty()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializable.Base.html#isEmpty(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider)), which `ObjectNode` derives from its super types, would be handy to check if a particular property needs to be updated.

Then, finally, you would need to parse the `ObjectNode` back into `GradeEto` type.

So the code in the Service might look like this:

```
@Service
public class GradeService {

    private ObjectMapper mapper;
    
    public GradeEto partialUpdate(Long id, ObjectNode updateInfo) throws IOException {

        Grade grade = gradeRepository.findById(id).get();
        GradeEto gradeeto = GradeMapper.mapToETO(grade);
        
        ObjectNode gradeEtoTree = mapper.valueToTree(gradeeto);
        
        updateInfo.fields().forEachRemaining(e -> {
            if (!e.getValue().isNull() && !e.getValue().isEmpty())
                gradeEtoTree.replace(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        });
        
        return mapper
            .readerFor(GradeEto.class) // creates an ObjectReader
            .readValue(gradeEtoTree);
    }
}
```

***Note:** it's worth to draw the reader's attention to the fact we also need to update the information in the Database. This logic is missing in both the Question and this Answer, since it's not relevant to the narrow technical problem of extracting the data that should be patched from JSON, but we definitely need to save the patched object (for instance a method that produces patched object can be wrapped with another method responsible for retrieving/updating the data in the database).*

Answer (score 0):

I do believe `org.springframework.cglib.beans.BeanMap` can solve your problem in elegant way:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String json = "{\n" +
            "    \"value\": 2,\n" +
            "    \"comment\": \"Test Idea\",\n" +
            "    \"subjectEntityId\": 20\n" +
            "}";


    Grade grade = new Grade();
    BeanMap map = BeanMap.create(grade);

    map.putAll(new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Map.class));


    assertThat(grade.value)
            .isEqualTo(2);
    assertThat(grade.subjectEntityId)
            .isEqualTo(20);
    assertThat(grade.comment)
            .isEqualTo("Test Idea");


}


@Data
static class Grade {

    int value;
    String comment;
    long subjectEntityId;
}
```